# How to add drive link in audio tag in html?

Tags: html, audio, drive

I am using audio tag in my html code for playing the audio in my webpage ,i have one doubt without passing directly audio to the audio tag i want to use google drive link(link contains one audio).please help me to acheive this ...

```
<audio controls autoplay>
<source src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/11wfYWiukbIZJQnDL385jQs2SGQA5ESbL/view?usp=drivesdk"></audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is correct only one problem you cant use the google drive link directly.

1.You should go to google drive and choose share file you will get something like the following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11wfYWiukbIZJQnDL385jQs2SGQA5ESbL/view?usp=sharing

2. Extract the id from URL 11wfYWiukbIZJQnDL385jQs2SGQA5ESbL
3. URL for playing the audio file https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=11wfYWiukbIZJQnDL385jQs2SGQA5ESbL
4. URL for downloading the audio file https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=11wfYWiukbIZJQnDL385jQs2SGQA5ESbL&export=download

your final code will be something like the following:

for playing:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
<source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=11wfYWiukbIZJQnDL385jQs2SGQA5ESbL">
</audio>
```

for downloading:

```
<a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=11wfYWiukbIZJQnDL385jQs2SGQA5ESbL&export=download"/>Download</a>
```

note: The auto play will not work on iPhone devices if saving power is enabled which is by default

Comment: i have one more doubt when ever the webpage opens the audio automatically play in background with no controls on the page, How to acheive this thing

Comment: simply remove controls from the audio tag.

Comment: it's not working if i remove the controls attribute from the tag

Comment: Its working fine for me can you please mention what device you are using (pc , phone , tablet , IOS , android) and what type of browser?

Comment: pc , phone and android

Comment: @HussainMohammed, sometimes it's working sometimes it's not working

Comment: maybe you can do it through javascript like this var myVideo = document.getElementById("my-video")    
myVideo.controls = false;